What is the expression of geometric variance for a multiplicative variable?
What would be the expression of a geometric variance for a multiplicative variable like investment returns?

Maybe this is a bit too obvious a case of self-promotion as it's not an answer to a question by somebody else? That usually doesn't go down well here.

Sharing new knowledge is self-promotion? New knowledge isn't welcome here? If so, I'll probably use ChatGPT instead, because new knowledge is the only thing that StackExchange could get that ChatGPT does not have yet. Good luck!

It's a free world, you can do whatever you want, and I think you know perfectly well what I mean. I'm just giving you a piece of advice, given the downvotes on your "question".

Thank you. I know the drill. I don't know why I keep hoping for better. Call me a masochist.

Using hyperlogarithmic arithmetic, we can construct this expression:
$$
\displaystyle \gamma(X) = \Bigg [\prod _{i=1}^{n}e^{\Bigg [\displaystyle \ln{\frac{x_{i}}{\Big (\displaystyle \prod _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\Big )^{\frac {1}{n}}}}\Bigg ]^2}\Bigg ]^{\frac {1}{n}}
$$
This article of mine outlines its construction.

you answered your own question?

Yes. Isn't that a feature of StackExchange?

I've seen that yes, but rarely on the same day as the question and rarer still citing a blog post written the day before the question itself.

Right. But discoveries that impactful are rare. Do yourself a favor and go read it. If you understand it, please tell me whether you still think it was not worth that little bit of self promotion. The original articles on LinkedIn generated 200,000 views over the weekend. For quant stuff, I'd say that's not too shabby. You be the judge.

Yes, you put this on LinkedIn and you got some feedback there too. Winfried Hallerbach gave you some really valuable comments.

Indeed. That was a great discussion, without any censorship.
